# open slack links in different chrome profiles (users)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, slack, slack-api

let say I have two chrome user, one of them is logged in with my work account and another one is logged as my personal account.

I logged in my GitHub/StackOverflow etc accounts with my personal accounts in chrome personal account . in the work user, I logged with my work accounts.  the chrome is the default browser in my machine.  what I need is that when there is a link has posted on slack I have this option to select with which user I want to open it.  it could happen in the slack level and the second level could be browser level to ask which user I want to open the link before opening it.

I asked it here because I feel this request is not just mine and a lot of people had/has the same preferences.

I found some option like
[browserchooser2](https://browserchooser2.com/) and [Account Surfer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/account-surfer/9phvp9rjr7r7?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) for windows OS but I haven't found anything for **MacOS**.

is there any other way to implement something that handle this?

many thanks for sharing your info with me about this.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so I'm not sure that it's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I think [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) (answers for your Apple questions) would have been more appropriate for this question. They have a [closely related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234950/open-specific-links-in-specific-browsers) question there.

Answer (score 3):

[Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/) on macOS can give you a prompt to open links in Chrome or Safari, which is almost what you want.

Or another tool called [Open in Profile](https://hikmetcancelik.com/open-in-profile/) lets you choose which Chrome profile will be used to open links clicked in other applications.

I don't know of any tool for macOS that lets you choose a specific browser profile every time you click a link. Of course the workaround is to copy and paste the link into the browser profile you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but looks like it just opens it in different browser not different profile

Comment: @Yuseferi I found another tool called "Open in Profile" which can open links in a specific profile, but still doesn't give you a prompt every time you click a link. :(

Answer (score 2):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/inchoate/5736cc1257066edd8fa643ca594a4778) solved it for me. Here's my "finicky" config, which opens all urls matching "app.raygun.com/*" in Chrome "Profile 4":

```js
module.exports = {
  defaultBrowser: "Google Chrome",
  options: {
    hideIcon: false,
    checkForUpdate: true,
  },
  handlers: [
    {
      match: ({ url }) => url.protocol === "slack",
      browser: "/Applications/Slack.app",
    },
    {
      match: "app.raygun.com/*",
      browser: {
        name: "Google Chrome",
        profile: "Profile 4",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: where did you put this code?

Comment: `~/.finicky`

the gist i linked to has complete instructions

Comment: what is finicky ? :)

Comment: https://github.com/johnste/finicky

Comment: Do you know if I can make a different slack account open on its own chrome profile?
Let say, I have two workspaces in slack and two profiles, I want one workspace open links in one profile and another workspace in another one

Comment: Yeah, same. I have a Company A Slack Workspace and a Company A Chrome Profile, I also have a Company B Slack Workspace and Chrome Profile. 

When I click a link in the A Slack workspace, I'd love it if it automatically opened the link in the A Chrome profile. Same with B Slack -> B Chrome.

Unfortunately, the links are typically google.drive documents, which don't have any consistent strings to match on.

Answer (score 0):

**Velja** seems to be doing pretty good job.
Support also profiles selection.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/velja/id1607635845?mt=12